# Use ImageMagick to compare Images

Tags: imagemagick

I want to compare a source png file to a compressed file.

I am using `imagemagick` and this command:

```
convert image1 image2 -compose Difference -composite \
       -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:
```

But what I get is a very odd number. I am looking from a number from 0-100%.

When I compared two totally different images I still get a 8.37885.

So good people of Ask Ubuntu, can you provide me with a command that will measure the difference between files properly and give me a number from 0-100?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is with the `colorspace gray` part of the command. This option checks only difference between gray colour of the images.

So the correct command should be

```
convert image1 image2 -compose Difference -composite  -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:
```

This should give you more appropriate answer.

Comment: You could try other methods like [this python script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1927681). Use that method which best suits your purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I will look into it, thank you for the command as well

Comment: @RegisteredUser __Warning__: that code seems to find the RMS error between the images’ histograms, __NOT between the images__ themselves. It's better to do __first the difference__ of the 2 images (if you want in a new image too), and _then_ to do the _squared sum_ of the normalized histogram bins.

Comment: @hastur can you please elaborate by providing the command. Maybe as another answer.